# Does a PendingIntent survive device restart?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, restart

Does a PendingIntent submitted to `LocationServices` survive device restart?  If not, what's the best practice for re-submitting without requiring the user to relaunch the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a PendingIntent submitted to LocationServices survive device restart?

No.

> If not, what's the best practice for re-submitting without requiring the user to relaunch the app?

Use an `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` to get control on a reboot, then set up your location requests again.